# How add custom fonts in react native version 0.61.5

Tags: react-native, fonts

As you may know react native >='60.0' does support auto linking, There are a lot of tutorial for adding custom fonts but most methods are out of date and confusing, All of them still using `react native link`

I wonder how can i add custom fonts in latest version of react native (0.61.5) that work on both of ios and android?

My `react-native.config.js` is like this:

```
  commands: [...ios.commands, ...android.commands],
  platforms: {
    ios: {
      linkConfig: ios.linkConfig,
      projectConfig: ios.projectConfig,
      dependencyConfig: ios.dependencyConfig,
    },
    android: {
      linkConfig: android.linkConfig,
      projectConfig: android.projectConfig,
      dependencyConfig: android.dependencyConfig,
    },
  },
  /**
   * Used when running RNTester (with React Native from source)
   */
  reactNativePath: '.',
  project: {
    ios: {
      project: './RNTester/RNTesterPods.xcworkspace',
    },
    android: {
      sourceDir: './RNTester',
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

you can still run react-native link :)

Here's a [github thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25852)  you can follow for this exact issue.

The steps that seem to be accepted are

1. Make a folder in root app as : `assets`
2. `fonts` folder in assets and put fonts in this folder
3. make a file in root : `react-native.config.js` (you already have this). Add assets reference in this file.

```
     module.exports = {
        project: {
        android: {}
        },
        assets: ['./assets/fonts/'],
     };
```

4. run `npx react-native link`
5. use the font as `style={{ fontFamily: "name of font" }}`
6. rerun the app:`npx react-native run-android`

Edit: fixed typo in file name

Comment: Please take a look to this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/NUgck28 i added  ```assets: ['./assets/fonts/'],``` like you see in screenshot.  ```react-native.config.js``` was in this address: ``` node_modules\react-native```

Comment: Seems like this method doesn't work in version '0.61.5', I did step by step as you said but i can't see any change in fonts

Comment: the filename should be `react-native.config.js` not `react-native-config.js`

Comment: If you don't see any changes after taking the above steps, try exiting the app and run `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

First add fonts path in rnpm in ppackage.json
 then run react-native link
 then add fonts  in Android of Asset folder